# Removing single-quote from a string in php

Tags: php

I have an HTML form that a user can input text into a `title` field, I then have php creating an HTML file called `title.html`

My problem is that users can input spaces and apostrophes into the title field that can't be used in the html file name. I replaced the spaces with underscores by using:

```
$FileName = str_replace(" ", "_", $UserInput);
```

However, I can't seem to remove single-quotes? I have tried using:

```
$FileName = preg_replace("/'/", '', $UserInput);
```

but this took `test's` and turned it into `test\s.html`.

Comment: You've got magic quotes turned on. This causes more problems than it solves, so turn them off.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Using your current str_replace method:

```
$FileName = str_replace("'", "", $UserInput);
```

While it's hard to see, the first argument is a double quote followed by a single quote followed by a double quote. The second argument is two double quotes with nothing in between.

With str_replace, you could even have an array of strings you want to remove entirely:

```
$remove[] = "'";
$remove[] = '"';
$remove[] = "-"; // just as another example

$FileName = str_replace( $remove, "", $UserInput );
```

Answer (score 11):

You can substitute in HTML entitiy:

```
$FileName = preg_replace("/'/", "\&#39;", $UserInput);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also be more restrictive in removing disallowed characters. The following regex would remove all characters that are not letters, digits or underscores:

```
$FileName = preg_replace('/[^\w]/', '', $UserInput);
```

You might want to do this to ensure maximum compatibility for filenames across different operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

```
$replace_str = array('"', "'", ",");
$FileName = str_replace($replace_str, "", $UserInput);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. You can strip just `'` and `"` with:

```
$FileName = str_replace(array('\'', '"'), '', $UserInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this function [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for alt attributes in images

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = "{'employees':[{'firstName':'John', 'lastName':'Doe'},{'firstName':'John', 'lastName':'Doe'}]}" ; 
$test = str_replace("'", '"', $test);
echo   $test;
$jtest = json_decode($test,true);
var_dump($jtest);
```