# Codeigniter allowing single quote in insert query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello i have read that "Codeigniter update and insert function values are escaped automatically producing safer queries."

But i tried to insert the data with the single quote in my contactUs form. But i have noticed that single quote is added in my database.

Here is my code

**Controller**:

```
        $data=array('name'=>$this->input->post('name'),'EmailId'=>$this->input->post('emailid'));

        $this->mymodel->insert_data('mytable',$data);//Sending data to the model
```

**Model**

```
    public function insert_data($table,$data)
{
    $this->db->insert($table,$data);
    return 'success.';
}
```

Any suggetions???

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Escape doesn't mean ignored. It means values will be inserted without  breaking the query even though you have single code in the data.

Comment: you could check this http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/security.html

Comment: Is there any reason why a single quote shouldn't make it to the database? Escaping doesn't mean removing. Have you tried Robert'); DROP TABLE students;--

Comment: Yeah i tried it but it havn't worked !!! Thnx...

Comment: @James If i used Robert'); DROP TABLE students;-- even the string with ' is inserted into my database...

Comment: If you very very very worried in that quote try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903219/removing-single-quote-from-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes aren't an issue if they have been properly escaped beforehand or if they have been inserted into the table using a prepared statement. Stripping out such characters completely could violate data integrity.