# How to handle quotes in filenames with PHP

Tags: php

I have a function to make thumbnails that works 99% of the time. Out of the 400 images I've tried to create thumbnails out of, only 2 failed. Both images have single quotes in them, and I'm wondering if that's the source of the problem? If it is, what should I do to fix it?

```
<?php

$image = "542Cute pets' hilarious snail dwelling life (06).jpg";
$image = "598BK_Fish'n_Crisp.jpg";

if ($image) {
    make_thumb("uploads", "thumbnails", $image, 500);
    echo $image;
}

function make_thumb($imageFrom, $imageTo, $image, $thumbWidth) {

    /* read the source image */
    $getFrom = $imageFrom."/".$image;

    $imageType =  exif_imagetype($getFrom);

    if ($imageType == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($getFrom);    
    }
    else if ($imageType == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
        $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($getFrom);   
    } 
    else if ($imageType == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
        $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($getFrom);   
    } 

    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

    /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
    $thumbHeight = floor($height * ($thumbWidth / $width));

    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);

    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                       $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, $width, $height);

    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */

    $dest = $imageTo."/".$image;

    if ($imageType == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
        imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);   
    }
    else if ($imageType == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
        imagepng($virtual_image, $dest);  
    } 
    else if ($imageType == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
        imagegif($virtual_image, $dest);  
    } 

} //end of function make_thumb($imageFrom, $imageTo, $image, $thumbWidth)

?>
```

**Note:** 
I'm getting the image name from a database. This is what it looks like in the database:

```
542Cute pets&#039; hilarious snail dwelling life (06).jpg
598BK_Fish&#039;n_Crisp.jpg
```

Comment: It depends how you are getting the image names. If you are storing them in a mysql database then retrieving them you should escape the single quotes before inserting them into the database.

Comment: @Brian I'm getting the image names from a database, and I've edited above to show you what the image names look like in the database.

Comment: Hi @jessica, you may want  to decode it back to its original filename before generating the thumbnail: $image = html_entity_decode($image); because it tries to look for the image with this filename: "598BK_Fish&#039;n_Crisp.jpg" when it actually is and should be "598BK_Fish'n_Crisp.jpg". Let us know how it goes, I posted this as a comment on my answer below too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm safely assuming that the single quote isn't that quite relevant to be preserved on the filename, so perhaps you could try to simply replace the quotes with a valid character or remove it entirely:

```
$image = str_replace("'", "", $image); //remove entirely
```

The first parameter on str_replace could be an array of characters you may want to remove entirely:

```
$removeArray[] = "'";
$removeArray[] = '@';
$removeArray[] = "^"; 

$image = str_replace( $removeArray, "", $image);
```

These filter should obviously go right after where your actual file names have been pulled or initialized:

```
$image = "542Cute pets' hilarious snail dwelling life (06).jpg";
$image = str_replace("'", "", $image);
```

You can see more about removing quotes here too: [removing single-quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903219/removing-single-quote-from-a-string-in-php)

It appears however, that you have escaped the filename with html entities before saving to your database. It actually modifies your actual file name so that it looks for:

```
imagejpeg($virtual_image, "598BK_Fish&#039;n_Crisp.jpg"); //can't find this one, sorry. :(
```

when it should supposedly be looking for:

```
imagejpeg($virtual_image, "598BK_Fish&'n_Crisp.jpg"); //this exists!
```

Comment: Why does it not work with single quotes if image names are allowed single quotes? And why does it only not work when creating thumbnails, but uploading the original image works? I'm so confuse.

Comment: Hi @jessica, how do you do? You mentioned that this is how it looks like when pulled from the db: 598BK_Fish&#039;n_Crisp.jpg, right? I can see that you have properly escaped the character (single-quote) with html entities (&#39;) so that uploading should work just as fine. With regards to creating thumbs as with your make_thumb(..) {...} function, it uses for one "imagejpeg" php function. When it tries to render the image, it actually looks for: 598BK_Fish&#039;n_Crisp.jpg, when it doesn't exist so you may want to decode it back to its original file name: $image = html_entity_decode($image);